# Filter entries of a relation field based on a field included in the related collection type

Tags: strapi

This is my second question about Strapi, I'm very new to it and a self-taught developer so please bear with me.

I'm on Strapi v4.15.4 (node v20.8.0) and I created 2 collection types named `user-test` and `article`. `user-test` collection type has the following attributes:

```
"attributes": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "confirmed": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
}
```

In addition to that `user-test` collection type has 4 entries:

| id | name | confirmed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | true |
| 2 | User2 | true |
| 3 | User3 | false |
| 4 | User4 | true |

`article` collection type has the following attributes:

```
"attributes": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "body": {
      "type": "blocks"
    },
    "authors": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "oneToMany",
      "target": "api::user-test.user-test"
    }
}
```

I'd like to filter, when creating/editing an entry in the `article` collection type from the admin panel, the entries of the relation field `authors` so that only the users for which the attribute `confirmed` is `true` are shown. In other words, I'd like to see only User1, User2 and User4 as entries of the relation field `authors`.

For now, I edited `src\api\article\controllers\article.js` in order to filter the entries in the `user-test` collection type but I don't know how to proceed from here. Also, I'm not sure why I cannot see anywhere the output of `console.log(confirmedUsers)`.

```
'use strict';

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;
const { sanitize } = require('@strapi/utils');

module.exports = createCoreController('api::article.article', ({ strapi }) => ({
    async getAuthors(ctx) {
      // Fetch confirmed users
      const confirmedUsers = await strapi.entityService.findMany('api::user-test.user-test', {
        filters: {
            confirmed: true,
          },
        });
    
        console.log(confirmedUsers);
    },
  }));
```

Any advice is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, you can’t do that in admin panel that easily, just answered same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77536272/how-to-check-permission-check-in-strapi-relational-field

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link @antokhio