# How to do permission-check in Strapi relational fields?

Tags: strapi

When in Strapi admin panel, for relational field all the collection is displayed without permission check. I want to use 'apply same permission' which is applied for listing view with Strapi permission. how do I enable that? - i want to display only those collections in relational field which area created by a particular user or the role where the user belong.

I have tried creating custom API, but i need a solution preferably without any custom API which utilize default Strapi functions.

Answer (score 0):

As for strapi 4.15.6, there is no way to filter relations in content editor view. The only way is to implement a custom json field and then build a relation data based on that json inside lifecycle hooks same as done here https://github.com/antokhio/strapi-plugin-categorizer